# Building a mini text-based python game as homework of learn python the hard way

Tags: python

I'm new to this website so please bear with my questioning problems on the website. I need some help to finish off this mini text-based game as homeowork of learning python the hard way book. This is the code I wrote. and I don't know the missing links and what I've done wrong. Help would be appreciated!

from sys import exit

def start():
    print "You are in an old temple."
    print "There is a door to your right and left or you can walk forwad."
    print "Which one do you take?"

```
choice = raw_input("> ")

if choice == "left":
    gold_room()
elif choice == "right":
    trap_room()
elif choice == "forward":
    monster_room()
else:
    dead("you got caught by the ancient gods and you must be killed.")
```

start()

def monster_room():
    print "you're in a room with a monster. what you gonna do?"

```
choice = raw_input("> ")
if "left" in choice:
print "you are going to the gold room"
gold_room()
elif "right" in choice:
print "you are going to the trap room"
trap_room()

else:
    dead("couldnt understand what did you say so you are dead!")
```

def gold_room():
    print "you chose the left room. now you are in a room with a pot of gold!"
    print "you can take the pot."
    print "or you can just rob the money in it."
    print "or you go go to other rooms."

```
choice = raw_input("> ")

if choice == "take the pot":
    print "you are a millionaire from now on!!!"

elif choice == "rob the money":
    dead("you will never rest in piece!")

else choice == "another room":
    monster_room()
```

def trap_room():
    print "you are now in a trap room."
    print "there is a hidden trap in this room."
    print "be careful!"
    print "you can go back to the  monster room"
    print "or you can find the trap"

```
choice = raw_input("> ")

if "find" in choice:
    start()
elif "back" in choice:
    gold_room()
```

def dead(why):
    print why, "rekt!"
    exit(0)

Comment: What's the problem? Can you specify that a little? Is the code running? Or throws it errors?

Comment: @linusg well, I'm pretty sure this piece of code has bugs that a beginner like me could not see and need changes to get the program running,but for the start :     
elif choice == "forward":
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: So do you get an error? Can you post the traceback?

Comment: @linusg How can I get a traceback? just copy/pasting error from the command line here you mean?

Comment: Run the code and cp the traceback as comment

Comment: cp is copy and paste...

Comment: @linusg   File "ex36.py", line 14
    elif choice == "forward":
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hmm can't see a `SyntaxError` there!

Comment: Is this the actual indentation in your code? If it is, your code has massive indentation problems and needs fixing. If it isn't, post code with the actual indentation you're using so we have some chance at knowing how it will run.

Comment: @linusg So what you think the problem is?are my functions written in a correct way? Is there a problem with my If conditions,Variables,...? basically what makes the program not running?

Comment: @khelwood what'd you mean by actual indentation and generally what are the indentation problems? and how can i post code with actual indentation?

Comment: @khelwood oh, no this is not the acutal indentation of the code!if changed the indentations for the sake of codes being in a same box! I'll change it asap!

Comment: Ok, fixed it. See my answer please!

Comment: Does it work now? Ah, and please accept one answer in the end.

Comment: @linusg Well, thanks. Now, I put the start() function at the end as you said and the start function is running but when I choose the "left" or "right" answer to go to other rooms(functions) it stops working. This is the traceback i get :   File "ex36.py", line 71, in <module>
    start()
  File "ex36.py", line 54, in start
    choice = input("> ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'right' is not defined


is there anyway to post the traceback the way it shows in the command line?

Comment: Ok, this is Python 2.x specific I think. Just replace all `input()` with `raw_input()` as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed it. Your code has several indentation mistakes, Python requires four spaces or one tab indentation after a `def` statement.

Another thing is, that you used `else` with a condition test (`else choice == "another room":`). That is wrong, it should be `elif choice == "another room":` or just else.

You also may have noticed, that I changed `raw_input()` to `input()`. This converts all inputs to strings (`input()` will interpret intergers as integers, lists as lists and so on...), and is also more secure.

The last thing is, you run your program (`start()`) before definign all called functions, this cannot work!

Your code (fixed):

```
from sys import exit

def start():
    print("You are in an old temple.")
    print("There is a door to your right and left or you can walk forwad.")
    print("Which one do you take?")

    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == "left":
        gold_room()
    elif choice == "right":
        trap_room()
    elif choice == "forward":
        monster_room()
    else:
        dead("you got caught by the ancient gods and you must be killed.")


def monster_room():
    print("you're in a room with a monster. what you gonna do?")

    choice = input("> ")
    if "left" in choice:
        print("you are going to the gold room")
        gold_room()
    elif "right" in choice:
        print("you are going to the trap room")
        trap_room()
    else:
        dead("couldn't understand what did you say so you are dead!")


def gold_room():
    print("you chose the left room. now you are in a room with a pot of gold!")
    print("you can take the pot.")
    print("or you can just rob the money in it.")
    print("or you go go to other rooms.")

    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == "take the pot":
        print("you are a millionaire from now on!!!")
    elif choice == "rob the money":
        dead("you will never rest in piece!")
    elif choice == "another room":
        monster_room()


def trap_room():
    print("you are now in a trap room.")
    print("there is a hidden trap in this room.")
    print("be careful!")
    print("you can go back to the  monster room")
    print("or you can find the trap")

    choice = input("> ")

    if "find" in choice:
        start()
    elif "back" in choice:
        gold_room()


def dead(why):
    print(why, "rekt!")
    exit(0)

start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would call the start() function at the end, after all the functions you defined. A usual way to write that is to write the following code at the end:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    start()
```

This basically means that the programm runs the start() function at the end, if you're executing the file.

Furthermore you have to leave spaces after defining a function. You wrote:

```
def monster_room():
print "you're in a room with a monster. what you gonna do?"
```

but it should be:

```
def monster_room():
    print "you're in a room with a monster. what you gonna do?"
```

If that didnt help, specify the problem

Comment: i edited the code, do you see any other problems in the code itself?

Comment: linugs answer below shoul have fixed it

Comment: except he used print("string), because he seems to be using python 3. if that does not work for you, try print "string" instead, which means youre using python 2.X